# I want to access the device mac in xamarin ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to access the device mac in xamarin ios but it always return 02:00:00:00:00:00.

```
   if (netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
                        netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                    {
                        var address = netInterface.GetPhysicalAddress();
                        return BitConverter.ToString(address.GetAddressBytes());
                }
            }    
            return "000000000000";
```

Comment: After iOS 7.0. Apple will reject if you want to get the MAC address and will always retrun a static value . As the Apple docs said  `Twolow-level networking APIs that used to return a MAC address now return thefixed value 02:00:00:00:00:00. The APIs in question are sysctl(NET_RT_IFLIST) and ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF). Developers using the value of the MAC address should migrate toidentifiers such as -[UIDevice identifierForVendor].This change affects all apps running on iOS 7` .

Comment: I used to work on app using mac address, and even this [open source native code](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan/issues/3) gave same issue you're getting. It is not possible to my knowledge as Lucas said. Although there were "hacky" workarounds in some versions, every time one worked apple patched it within weeks. There are apps that can get access it to it, but I'm guessing they have exclusive partnerships w/ apple.